# Can I use free fonts on a website which contains banners?

Tags: fonts, free, website-features, licenses, banners

I should choose a font for my website, which is hosted by a web platform (Altervista) and has its own second-level domain with the .com extension. It will be a blog basically, but it will contain advertisement as well.

I see that there are many fonts available everywere on the internet, both free and paid, but I have some general doubts about the licenses, since some of them are delivered or sold at different prices depending on which platform they are supposed to be used (server, desktop, apps, and so on...)

- is it possible to find **fonts** which can be **freely** used on a **website** which does contain **banners**?

Comment: Have you checked Google fonts and typekit website?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Just check the license to make sure that it doesn't have a "Free for non-commercial use only" restriction.